# How to "revendor" my repository on github?

Tags: github, vendor

I recently made a change to a repository on github.com and tried importing the amended repo in my golang program. I got a lot of compilation errors, not related to the code changes that I had done, but elsewhere.

From another thread I came to know about "revendoring".

What is revendoring? Why is it needed? How to revendor my repository on github?

Thanks!